# Get products based delivery fee of shop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to get products where i am getting delivery fee from front-end in this form:

```
params[delivery_rate_min]
params[delivery_rate_max]
```

In the shops table i have a column of

```
t.integer "shipping_rate_cents", default: 0, null: false
```

I want to filter products according to the value

I have written an incomplete query. Can someone please help me to complete it

```
@products = @products.joins(:shop).where(shop: {delivery_rate_cents:  })
```

Comment: What is the relation between shop and restauranr?

Comment: There is no restaurant.. That's shop. I've edited it. It was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
@products = @products.joins(:shops).where(
            'delivery_rate_cents >= ? AND delivery_rate_cents <= ?', params[:delivery_min_cost], params[:delivery_max_cost]
          )
```

Figured it out myself